# What in cross validation from co-correspondence analysis indicates sufficient axes numbers?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, predictor, ecology, correspondence-analysis

The coca function at cocorresp package disponible for R provides a predictive way to relate two biological composition datasets. I need help to understand one step from examples on documentation material cocorresp.pdf - page 6, available online. Below, I try to explain my doubt using some lines and outputs from the material discribed before, assuming the cocorresp packge is installed and loaded:

```
> data(beetles) #load example dataset
> data(plants) #load example dataset
> beetles <- log(beetles + 1) #data transformation 
> bp.pred <- coca(beetles ~ ., data = plants) # predictive CoCA
```

[image]

```
> crossval(beetles, plants) #retain only the useful PLS components for a parsimonious model.
```

[image]

On page 6 from instruction material, following the command line "crossval(beetles, plants)" we can see this note:

"so 2 axes are sufficient"

Here comes my question: What in the output from crossval() leads to "**so 2 axes are sufficient**" note?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument here is basically that, although models with six or seven COCA axes have slightly better fit than one with two COCA axes, the improvement is small over and above the simpler model. Although we (I) don't do this in the software, I would suspect that the standard error of CV fit values for the six- or seven-axis models would actually indicate that they are indistinguishable from the two-axis model (the so-called one-standard-error rule). hence, in the spirit of parsimony, we would favour the simpler model over the more complex ones.

This example basically repeats the analysis from the paper (which was based on the original Matlab code that I ported to R) so you can look there for more narrative, although my recollection is that the paper doesn't go into that much of detailed explanation of the results.

Comment: You can apply whatever transformation is appropriate or relevant to the question at hand. As cover is a doubly bounded value, one often sees other transformation applied, such as the arc-sine transformation or log-ratio transformation.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted the question about transformation during edition.That question was: - In the example above, if plant dataset was in coverage proportion*, it is ok to apply the same log(x+1) transformation as in bettle?                     
*eg: inside 1m² if one herb species fufill this area, it is scored as 100, or, if fill only half of this area, it is scored as 50. If it dont fill any area, it is scored as 0.

Comment: Also another doubt and a complement: DOUBT: if the COCA axes values from crossval() were all negative, is correct to invalidate the model? COMPLEMENT: On the paper you referencied* I belive this is the part you remembered: "CO-CA has a local maximum (7,8%) for two axes and a global maximum (8.7%) at seven axes. We retain the two-dimensional solution to keep the model as simple as possible" . After your explanation this make much more sense for me!                   
 *Cajo, Schaffers Co-Correspondence Analysis : A New Ordination Method to Relate Two Community Compositions

Comment: Re the doubt, I would say that the model has no more predictive power than a random predictor. Ecologically, therefore, there is no predictive relationship between species matrix $\mathbf{X}$ and species matrix $\mathbf{Y}$.